# Knowledge Graph Search API Key not found

Tags: python, google-api

I'm trying to run a snippet for scraping data from Google using the     [Knowledge Graph Search API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/).

I've generated a API key following instructions on [this page](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/how-tos/authorizing).

When I run the snippet:

```
"""Example of Python client calling Knowledge Graph Search API."""
import json
import urllib

query = 'Taylor Swift'
service_url = 'https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search'
params = {
    'query': query,
    'limit': 10,
    'indent': True,
    'key': 'my_API_key',
}
url = service_url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params)
response = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
for element in response['itemListElement']:
  print element['result']['name'] + ' (' + str(element['resultScore']) + ')'
```

I get an API key error:

```
{u'error': {u'status': u'INVALID_ARGUMENT', u'message': u'API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key.', u'code': 400, u'details': [{u'@type': u'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', u'links': [{u'url': u'https://console.developers.google.com/project/339535230623/apiui/credential', u'description': u'Google developer console API key'}]}]}}
```

My API key appears on the Google APIs [credential's page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=afparsing&folder&organizationId) tough...

How to fix this issue ?

Edit: this is Python 2.7 code

Answer (score 0):

I simply hadn't enabled my API key. 
I followed the instructions in [this page](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en) and it worked :)